# Sed substitution output using regular expressions

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a sedfile called tester.txt that contains this code.

```
s/\(\\ref\s*\) \(\w*,\) \(``\(\w*\s*\)*,\) \(.*\)/\1 ll\2 ll\3 dd\4/
/^\ref{A-Za-z}*/p
```

When I run these commands on the following text, I get some incorrect output. I don't understand why the "alright" part is being repeated. Shouldn't the ".*" match up with the rest of the text? Not sure why this is coming up. Any help would be appreciated.

output:

```
 \ref llthis, ll``is hard af alright, ddalright
```

original text:

```
 \ref this, ``is hard af alright, finally,
```

Comment: Backrefs are numbered by their opening paren. Nested parens increment the number when opened. So (ref) (w) (``(w)) (.*) is numbered (1:ref) (2:w) (3:``(4:w)) (5:.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within:

```
\(\\ref\s*\) \(\w*,\) \(``\(\w*\s*\)*,\) \(.*\)
```

just count your capture groups:

```
1: \(\\ref\s*\)
2: \(\w*,\)
3: \(``\(\w*\s*\)*,\)
4: \(\w*\s*\)
5: \(.*\)
```

The 4th one (referenced later as `\4`) is inside the 3rd one (`\3`) hence the repetition. You don't show what output you actually expected to get so it's a guess but maybe you wanted:

```
\1 ll\2 ll\3 dd\5
```

instead of:

```
\1 ll\2 ll\3 dd\4
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. This is very helpful information. Cheers.